# Preserve the order while making queries

Tags: sql

I have this query where I want to preserve the order

```
SELECT a FROM TABLE WHERE id in (2,45, 87, 10,12, 41, 29)
```

Now I want the a values in that order I mean a for 2 followed by a for 45 followed by a for 87. How can I accomplish this in sql

Answer (score 5):

In MySQL you can use ORDER BY [FIELD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

```
SELECT a
FROM yourtable
WHERE id IN (2, 45, 87, 10, 12, 41, 29)
ORDER BY FIELD (id, 2, 45, 87, 10, 12, 41, 29)
```

In databases that don't support FIELD you can use a CASE expression instead:

```
SELECT a
FROM yourtable
WHERE id IN (2, 45, 87, 10, 12, 41, 29)
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN id = 2 THEN 1
    WHEN id = 45 THEN 2
    WHEN id = 87 THEN 3
    WHEN id = 10 THEN 4
    WHEN id = 12 THEN 5
    WHEN id = 41 THEN 6
    WHEN id = 29 THEN 7
END
```

Comment: Yeah that is one possibility but in my case the ids are generated by another query like SELECT id FROM TABLE 2 WHERE condition. So how can I include that as well

Comment: @user9093: In your case the ids don't come in any specific order. If you had a specific order (eg insertion date) you could use a JOIN and order by the appopriate column. But it appears that you don't have this, so probably  nothing you can do unless you add the missing column.

Answer (score 0):

If your id values come from another query, and their order matters, then that query must have its own ORDER BY clause that produces the ids in the correct order. You can then use a join instead of an IN clause, with this ORDER BY clause. Here's a standard SQL query to do that.

```
with SelectIDs(id,position) as (
  select 
    id,
    row_number() over (
      order by columnA, columnB
    )
  from table2
  where <your where condition>
)
  select T.*
  from yourTable as T
  join SelectIDs as I
  on I.id = T.id
  order by I.position;
```

If the ids you're matching are distinct and not NULL, the result should be what you want.